# React redux nested smart component - state isn't mapped to props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am creating a drinks counter that will count the amount of drinks consumed as part of a project to learn redux.

I have some initial state that has a drinks property that contains a collection of drinks and their current count:

```js
//State

{
  drinks: {
    coffee: 0,
    water: 0,
  }
  //...
}
```

I have created a `Counter` presentational component:

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import Button from './Button';

const ucFirst = string => string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);

const Counter = ({name, count, onIncrement, onDecrement}) => (
 <div className="counter">
  <h2>{ucFirst(name)}</h2>
  <span>{count}</span>
  <Button onClick={() => {onIncrement(name)}}>+</Button>
  <Button onClick={() => {onDecrement(name)}}>-</Button>
 </div>
);

Counter.propTypes = {
 name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
 count: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
 onIncrement: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
 onDecrement: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

export default Counter;
```

Followed by a `DrinkCounter` container component:

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { incrementDrink, decrementDrink } from '../actions'
import Counter from '../components/Counter'

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
 count: state.drinks[ownProps.drink],
 name: ownProps.drink
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
 onIncrement: drink => dispatch(incrementDrink(drink)),
 onDecrement: drink => dispatch(decrementDrink(drink))
})

export default connect(
 mapStateToProps,
 mapDispatchToProps
)(Counter)
```

This works as expected, if I add

```
<DrinksContainer name="coffee" />
```

into my `App` component.

Now this is where the problem begins, I want to create two more components one presentational and one container that will map over the keys of my `drinks` object and output a `DrinkCounter` for each, I have the following code but I'm getting the error "Failed prop type: The prop `name` is marked as required in `Counter`, but its value is `undefined`"

Here is `List` container:

```js
import React, {Fragment} from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import DrinkCounter from '../containers/DrinkCounter'

const List = ({drinks}) => {
  return (
 <Fragment>
   {
   Object.keys(drinks).map(
    (drink, index) => (<DrinkCounter name={drink} key={index} />)
   )
  }
 </Fragment>
  )
}

List.propTypes = {
 drinks: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default List
```

and here is the `DrinksList` container:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import List from '../components/List';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
 drinks: state.drinks 
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(List);
```

Could someone explain where I'm going wrong?

Comment: feels like that within your `DrinkCounter` you use `Counter` component but you don't pass `name` property to it.

Comment: I know but in the `List` component where the map is happening I add the `name` prop like this `<DrinkCounter name={drink} key={index} />`

Comment: what does your `DrinkCounter` component look like?

Comment: The code for the `DrinkCounter` component is in the question body

Comment: well, not really. you're not showing anything but its `mapStateToProps` & `mapDispatchToProps` methods. where is the rest?

Comment: btw, you're exporting `connect(Counter)` from `DrinkCounter`. any reason for that or a typo?

Comment: `DrinkCounter` exports `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Counter)` by default. `connect` returns a function that when called with a component (in this case `Counter`) it will return a new component which is the passed component complete with props filled from state. So when I call `<DrinkCounter name={drink} key={index} />` it is essentially the same as `<Counter name={drink} key={index} count={state.drinks[drink]} onIncrement={incrementDispatchFn} onDecrement={decrementDispatchFn} />`.

Comment: In the process of responding I've realised my mistake! I'm passing `name` as a prop to `DrinkCounter` when it should be `drink`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the problem, in the `List` component I am giving the wrong prop to `DrinkCounter` I'm passing `name` when actually it should be `drink`.